# $(x,y)$ pairs in lattice $Z^2$ that are co-prime with euclidean-norm at most $k$

Tags: asymptotics, normed-spaces, integer-lattices

Let $B(k) = \{(x,y)\in Z^2 ~|~ x^2+y^2\leq k^2\}$, where $Z$ is the set of integers.

It is quite straight forward to show that $|B(k)|$ is $\Theta(k^2)$.

My question is whether the number of co-prime pairs $(x,y)$ in $B(k)$ also $\Theta(k^2)$, or whether it is asymptotically smaller than $k^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Primitive Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem#The_primitive_circle_problem), the asymptotics are still $\Theta(k^2)$ (and the constant is known to be $6/\pi$).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a simple argument to prove the $\Theta(k^2)$ bound for this (i.e. without using the coprime probability property)?

Comment: @chyle I'm unaware, but I'm not familiar with various proofs of this problem. From searching a bit it appears that one can convert between a "coprime lattice counting" problem and a "standard lattice counting problem" via the relation $C_D(k) = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(m) B_D(k/m^2)$, where $D$ is an arbitrary planar domain (a circle in your case). I haven't found a proof for this, but it is stated in eq. 1.4 of [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa76/aa7634.pdf) and attributed to vinogradov ...

Comment: Note that this seems to implicitly use something quite close to the "coprime probability" though. The probability that 2 integers are coprime generally formalized via $1/\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$ (that this is the proper expression is established via the Euler product for $\zeta$). The theory of Dirichlet series shows that $1/\zeta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(n)/n^s$, i.e. $1/\zeta(2)$ is closely related to the expression I quoted above.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.